# How to create a custom UICollectionViewCell and add image from URL to it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

i want to load my images i've got from flickr into uicollectionsview
i followed allot of guides but they all fall apart when i have to do this

```
    cell.imageView.image
```

it basically says it can't find imageView in object of uicollectionsviewcell

i also tried a method like this, but it didn't work

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"flickerCell";

UICollectionViewCell *flickerCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
flickerCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[flickerCell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[flickerCell addSubview:recipeImageView];
return flickerCell;
}
```

recipieImageView is something i got some a tutorial.
my cell is named flickerCell in the storyboard and photoURLs has 33 objects i can view in code . so it's all there. also photoURLs is a NSMutablearray
how ever. in this method my recipeImageView returns nill ???
i have a cell.h which has the imageView

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Cell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

so if anyone know a way i can display all the images that photoURLs has in a uicollectionview it would be very helpful

**UPDATE**
i now tried a new way but still not working. imageView returns nil

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"flickerCell";

Cell *flickerCell = (Cell*) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

flickerCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return flickerCell;
}
```

**UPDATE AGAIN**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"flickerCell";
Cell *flickerCell = (Cell*) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"flickercell = %@", flickerCell);
flickerCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
flickerCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
return flickerCell;
```

}
with this in viewdidload

```
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"flickerCell"];
```

NSLOG of flickerCell returns this :

```
    flickercell = <Cell: 0x9dec2f0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 120 115); layer = <CALayer: 0x9dec430>>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I get it you are using a custom UICollectionViewCell. However in the method you pasted you create a pointer to UICollectionViewCell which has no built-in UIImageView. So that's why you get the error in the first try. 
About the second - did you register your custom UICollectionViewCell class with the CollectionView?

======

Edit: after a long chat with the poster we solved all the problems.

- The first one was that the registered class was UICollectionViewCell, not the inherited custom one.
- The second problem was that the view was actually in a xib file, so `registerNib:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:` should be used instead of  `registerClass:forCellWithReuseIdentifier:`
- The third one was that the custom cell was configured in a storyboard xib instead of its own xib file that is wired with the custom class ("Cell" in our case)
- And fourth main problem was that UIImage was incorrectly created with `imageNamed:` which should be used only for images that are embedded in the project. The correct way to create the UIImage in our case is: `flickerCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`

Comment: not sure what your talking about, still kinda new to this. but let me see.
i've imported my Cell.h which is a uicollectionsviewcell and in that i have a imageView. how ever still not working neither methods

Comment: how to point to a UICollectionViewCell with a UIImageView then ?

Comment: OK. In your viewDidLoad() method you have to do something like:

Comment: `[myCollectionView registerClass:[MyCustomCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomCellIdentifier"];` 
or
`[myCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomCellIdentifier"];` 
Depending on whether you setup your custom cell just from code or with a xib file.
Then in cellForItem... you do:
`MyCustomCell *flickerCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`
Then you will be able to access the imageView inside the cell.

Comment: i have this '[self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"flickerCell"];' in my viewdidload allrdy

Comment: Ok, but in this way you register the stock UICollectionViewCell class. This means that when you call dequeue you will get an instance of UICollectionViewCell. It has no imageView in it, hence you get the error. Instead of `[UICollectionViewCell class]` you should write `[MyCustomCell class]`. Replace 'MyCustomCell' with whatever you have named your custom cell class. As I get it from your code it is just 'Cell', so `[Cell class]`.

Comment: couldn't get it to work with your examples. how ever i modified the one i had to this [self.collectionView registerClass:[Cell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"flickerCell"]; is that ok ?

Comment: Yep, if your custom class is called 'Cell', that's what I meant.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42734/discussion-between-kennyvb-and-axe)

Comment: registerNib: forCellWithReuseIdentifier was the solution for me :) .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

It may help you.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *identifier = @"flickerCell";

        Cell *flickerCell = (Cell*) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        flickerCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        flickerCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        return flickerCell;
}
```

Comment: recipeImageView was something i created from UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[flickerCell viewWithTag:100]; don't think you can' just state it without making it first ?

Comment: @KennyVB you actually want to access `imageview` which is declared in your `Cell` class inherited from `UICollectionCell`. I just shown how to access it.

Comment: ! use of undeclared identifier 'recipeImageView' that's what it says when i try your code... as i said recipeImageView was created from UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[flickerCell viewWithTag:100]; there for i can't just use it without making it first. or i'm a wrong about something ?

Comment: @KennyVB Okay got it. I not saw that. Thanks for correcting. I updates as well.

Comment: hmm just tried your updated code. it validates but it crashes with this
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionViewCell imageView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaadce70'

Comment: see the NSLog of `flickerCell` and see whats going there. Whether it have imageView property or not?

Comment: nslog reports this. don't know what to make of it ?
flickercell = <Cell: 0x9dec2f0; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 120 115); layer = <CALayer: 0x9dec430>>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42733/discussion-between-bhumeshwer-katre-and-kennyvb)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create a custom UICollectionViewCell class with custom the animation while tap the UICollectionViewCell.
So, You don't need to add any specific method/action for the animation.

- In storyboard - Add a UICollectionViewCell with cell identifier, UIImageView and UILabel.
- Assign both UIImageView and UILabel property to Storyboard cell.
- Import the 'UviCollectionCell.h' in your view controller.

  ## In YourViewController.h

  ```
  - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      UviCollectionCell *cell = (UviCollectionCell *)  [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collection_cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      [cell.cellImageView setBackgroundColor: [UIColor randomColor]];
      // You can add your image here.
      cell.cellImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
      [cell.cellTitle setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"S %ld - R %ld",(long)indexPath.section,(long)indexPath.row]];

      //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor randomColor];
      return cell;
  }
  ```

  ## UviCollectionCell.h

  ```
      #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

      @interface UviCollectionCell : UICollectionViewCell<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

      @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cellImageView;
      @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellTitle;

      @end
  ```

  ## UviCollectionCell.m

  ```
      #import "UviCollectionCell.h"

      @implementation UviCollectionCell

      // Initialize the collectiion cell based on the frame and add the tap gesture recognizer for custom animation
      - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
          self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

          // Custom animation while tap the CollectionCell view.
          UITapGestureRecognizer *tapReconizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectedCellAnimation)];
          [tapReconizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired : 1];
          [tapReconizer setDelegate:self];
          [self addGestureRecognizer:tapReconizer];

          return self;
      }

      // Initialize the collection cell based on the nscoder and add the tap gesture recognizer for custom animation
      -(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
           self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
          // Custom animation while tap the CollectionCell view.
          UITapGestureRecognizer *tapReconizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectedCellAnimation)];
          [tapReconizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired : 1];
          [tapReconizer setDelegate:self];
          [self addGestureRecognizer:tapReconizer];

           return self;
      }

      // Initialize the collectiion cell and add the tap gesture recognizer for custom animation
      -(id) init {
          self = [super init];

          // Custom animation while tap the CollectionCell view.
          UITapGestureRecognizer *tapReconizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(selectedCellAnimation)];
          [tapReconizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired : 1];
          [tapReconizer setDelegate:self];
          [self addGestureRecognizer:tapReconizer];

          return self;
      }

      // Customize the animation while tap the UICollectionViewCell with custom animation duration.
      - (void)selectedCellAnimation {
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn) animations:^{
              CALayer *layer = self.layer;
              CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
              rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 25.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
              layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
          } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
              [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut) animations:^{
                  CALayer *layer = self.layer;
                  CATransform3D rotationAndPerspectiveTransform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                  rotationAndPerspectiveTransform.m24 = 0;
                  rotationAndPerspectiveTransform =CATransform3DRotate(rotationAndPerspectiveTransform, 0.0f * M_PI / 180.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                  layer.transform = rotationAndPerspectiveTransform;
              } completion:nil];
          }];
      }

      @end
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

what does `[photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` return?

For use with `imageNamed:` it MUST return a `NSString` object which is the name of a resource located in the main bundle. It won't work with a URL, even less if this URL is pointing to a remote URL.

Anyway, you shouldn't use `imageNamed`. This method caches the image in the system's cache, which is not optimal/required in a collection/table view. Instead use an alternative method to create the `UIImage` object.

A solution to your problem depends whether you need to load your image data from a remote server or if these resources are located on the device.

In the first case, you need an asynchronous approach in conjunction with a "placeholder image" which represents an image while being loaded when it is displayed in the cell.

In the second case, you may use a simple synchronous approach to load images (similar to your existing solution, but using `imageWithContentsOfFile:` for example), unless the images are large, in which case you need an asynchronous approach too.

Note: your code has a few other issues, too - but first and foremost you need to tell where your images come from.

A possible (but not optimal) solution for loading images *from the disk* on the device:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"flickerCell";
    FlickerCell* flickerCell = (FlickerCell*) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    flickerCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSURL* url = [self.photoURLs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // file URL
    flickerCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[url path]];
    return flickerCell;
}
```

A more sophisticated solution would *load* and *decode* images *ahead* in a background thread - before they are actually displayed. That way, *when* they are actually displayed, the images are possibly already encoded and will render much faster. This also requires a cache.